# using a service in a method

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to retrieve the user's geolocation and then use it in a separate api call.  When I do the following I get this error.  The service is 'getLegislatorByLocation' and it's in the geoSuccess method.

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLegislatorByLocation' of undefined

```
export class LocalLegislatorsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _legislatorService: LegislatorService) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {       
        this.geoFindUser();                     
    }



    geoFindUser(): void {

        if (!navigator.geolocation) {
            this.geoSupport = false;
            return;
        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.geoSuccess, this.geoError);
    }

    geoSuccess(position): void {
        this.geoSupport = true;
        this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        this._legislatorService.getLegislatorByLocation(this.latitude, this.longitude)
            .subscribe(legislators => this.legislators = legislators, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error); 
    }

    geoError(): void {
        console.log('Unable to retrieve location');
        this.geoSupport = false;
    }
}
```

Do I somehow need to inject the service into the method?

Comment: Can you please try to add `console.log(_legislatorService)` to the constructor and post what it prints? You don't need to do anything but injecting using the constructor. There is something else wrong. Did you add `LegislatorService` anywhere to `providers`?

Comment: The `LegislatorService`, if written by you, needs the `@Injectable` decorator and should be added to the providers of your component or the providers array in your bootstrap call.

Comment: It does have the @Injectable decorator.  It works fine if I call it in the "ngOnInit()"  The issue occurred when I moved it into the geoSuccess() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code loses the `this.` scope with this line

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.geoSuccess, this.geoError);
```

if you change it to

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => this.geoSuccess(pos), this.geoError);
```

it should work.

The magic is the `=>` which ensures that when `geoSuccess()` gets called from within `getCurrentPosition()` `this` will still point to the current instance of `LocalLegislatorsComponent` while otherwise it will point to the `getCurrentPosition()` function or whereever `geoSuccess` is being called from.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Another way of working around would be

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.geoSuccess.bind(this), this.geoError);
```

Comment: Exactly like magic.  This did the trick, and thanks for the very informative response!